# Build angular-cli app with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, angular, phonegap-build, angular-cli

What are the steps needed to build an angular-cli application with Phonegap?

A problem arises with `<base href="/">`, causing it to not be able to load scripts relative to the index path. So changing to `href=""` or `href="./"` works for local files, sometimes, however does not work for external links.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng build --base-href .

That'll fix your base href issues. However Angular CLI is far from perfect. For one, your debugging/sourcemap URLs will break. Second, the TS files and the webpack:// folder wont' show up. .. but you'll be able to run your app minus debugging.

Updated: I put up a basic example using WebPack. While it doesn't give you everything Angular-CLI has, it is close and can be enhanced.
https://github.com/maliksahil/AngularCordovaWebPack